# C# Convert DatagridViewTextbox to DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridView table that is already filled.
Now, when I click on a cell in the DataGridView, I want to make a ComboBox out of the cell, where I can then choose a selection of "Items".

Dgv_Data_List is my DataGridView.

```
        private void Dgv_Data_List_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell CboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            CboCell.Items.AddRange("Yes", "No");
            Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = CboCell;  <--At this point my program crashes
    }
```

I don't want any fixed comboboxes. They should be created at runtime as soon as they are needed.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Why you _don't want any fixed comboboxes._?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear how the grid is filled with data. You may get away with this if the columns and rows are manually added, however if the grid has a `DataSource`, then when you “double-click” into a cell and set the cell as a combo box as you show… then the “current” cells value better be a “Yes” or “No” or you will get the grids `DataError` complaining about the value in the cell not being a valid combo box value.

I would think you would have to “delete” the current cells value just to avoid the possible error. Something like…

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell CboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
CboCell.Items.AddRange("Yes", "No");
Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "";
Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = CboCell;
```

Setting the cells value to a blank `string` will work. HOWEVER, if the column type of the cells underlying data source is of a numeric type… then you will get the grids `DataError` complaining that the “Yes” or “No” value is not a valid numeric value… so technically this will ONLY work if the column type is a `string` type column. As most of this is unknown, I can only assume ALL the cells are of a `string` type.

Comment: Yes this is a good Idea. But If I try this, the Combobox hast no value to choose.

Comment: Hmm... in my tests, the posted code worked as expected and I could select either "Yes" or "No" from the combo box. Is there something different you are doing that is different from my posted code? This is in the grids `CellDoubleClick` event. And are you getting any errors? And if so what are those errors?

Comment: No it is exact the same code.

Comment: Well, if you are not getting any errors, then something else must be going on. I have tested the posted code in the grids `CellDoubleClick` event and can confirm it works as expected with or without the grid having a `DataSource.` Also, does the combo box itself show and there are no values to select from? How is the grid filled with data? Can you [edit] your question and "add" the code you are using.

Comment: OK Now i found my problem. Sorry for that. I had the Dgv_Data_List.Columns["test"].ReadOnly on true. So it was not possible to change the values.

Answer (score 0):

As the code given, you created `comboboxcell` but not convert the grid view. so do this instead.

```
this.dataGridView1[CboCell] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
```

Try this in the place of creating the `comboboxcell`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that doesn't help me